# how to send email with anonymous name from xampp using php

Tags: php, email, smtp, xampp

I am trying to set my localhost to send email from xampp using PHP. how to do it so that I will be able to send email with any name to a valid email id.for example I should be able to send email from address mymail@rajkumar.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be using PHP's `mail` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

The documentation says:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

The from address on an email is included in the $additional_headers.  Look at this example below (also from PHP.net):

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

**EDIT (elaborating spam notice):**

Anyone can use mail headers to send an email from any address.  For example, I can send an email to you and make it look like the sender is `urgent@ups.com`.  This email could contain some malicious files or a link to a phishing site.  When you use your localhost XAMPP server to send mail from `mymail@rajkumar.com` many email clients will try to verify that the mail indeed originated from `rajkumar.com`.  Since it originated from whatever the IP address of your localhost server is and not the domain you claimed to be sending from, it most likely will be marked as spam.

Comment: i have not understood your last sentence i.e. " mail is often marked as spam when sent from a server (localhost) that does not match the from email address's domain (rajkumar.com)."..can you please elaborate it